# precompiled header in visual studio 2022

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2022, precompiled-headers

I am pretty new to creating a dll file, and I would like to use a precompiled header, so that I can build faster. I am currently using the Visual Studio 2022.

Here is my directory structure looks like

```
Foo
|-- include
|     |-- pch.h
|     |-- globalPch.h
|
|-- src
|     |-- pch.cpp
|     |-- globalPch.cpp
|     |-- dllmain.cpp
|     |-- FooDir
|     |     |-- A.cpp
|     |     |-- A.hpp
|     |     |-- B.cpp
|     |     |-- B.hpp
```

I have globalPch.h, which has all the standard library and some user typedef, and I have my pch.h to include all globalPch.h. So, I've set up the `pch.cpp` to `create (/Yc)` Precompile Header. Then, globalPch.cpp to `Use(/Yu)`, and I realize that I actually put the relative path of pch.h into pch.cpp.

But I am getting an error saying that `command-line option was not found in the source file` on pch.cpp file. I right-clicked the pch.cpp --> `Precompiled Headers` --> `Precompiled Header File` --> set the path to pch.h. I still got the same error as above.

Is there a solution to this? or I looked at some OpenSource code if someone has a precompile header problem like me. But it looks like they've put pch.h and pch.cpp into the same dir. Is this conventional?

Comment: Your title says Visual Studio, but your tags say C++Builder instead.  Which IDE are you actually using? PCHs are handled very differently in one IDE vs the other.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: IMHO you really don't want to use precompiled headers, unless your project is really huge.  They are not worth the hassle of using and maintaining.  If one header file is changed, the PCH has to be rebuilt.  Measure.  Build without PCH and measure with using PCH.  Is the difference significant?

Comment: I think the precompiled header file must be in the compiler search path `/I`